# Finite energy configuration in static electric and magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

Let $\textbf{B}$ and $\textbf{E}$ are source-free, static magnetic and electric fields in $\mathbb{R}^3$ respectively, which are infinitely many times differentiable. Furthermore, they satisfy either of the Bogomolny equations $$\textbf{E}=+\textbf{B} \hspace{0.3cm} \text{or} \hspace{0.3cm}\textbf{E}=-\textbf{B}.$$ I need to show that as long as the equations describe a finite energy equations, $\textbf{E}=\textbf{B}=0$.

Reference: Rudolph Ortvay Competition '97. I used a very crude method of solving the question by writing the corresponding energy densities of the fields, and writing the integral over all space. Since the integral has to be finite, I figured that the integrand has to be zero. But I'm guessing that the solution isn't correct. The question was accompanied with a hint which asked the reader to examine the twists of the fields at infinity. I didn't understand what it meant.

1. How do I solve it?
2. Also, do the Maxwell equations have source-free, static solutions too, besides the EM wave?